# How to get watch to run a bash script with quotes

Tags: linux, bash, grep, quotes, watch

I'm trying to have a lightweight memory profiler for the matlab jobs that are run on my machine. There is either one or zero matlab job instance, but its process id changes frequently (since it is actually called by another script).

So here is the bash script that I put together to log memory usage:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`ps aux | grep '[M]ATLAB' | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ -n $pid ]]
then
    \grep VmSize /proc/$pid/status
else
    echo "no pid"
fi
```

when I run this script in bash like this:

```
./script.sh
```

it works fine, giving me the following result:

```
VmSize:  1289004 kB
```

which is exactly what I want.

Now, I want to run this periodically. So I run it with `watch`, like this:

```
watch ./script.sh
```

But in this case I only receive:

```
no pid
```

Please note that I know the matlab job is still running, because I can see it with the same pid on `top`, and besides, I know each matlab job take several hours to finish.

I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with the quotes I have when setting pid. I just can't figure out how to fix it. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

PS.
In the man page of `watch`, it says that commands are executed by `sh -c`. I did run my script like `sh -c  ./script` and it works just fine, but `watch` doesn't.

Comment: +1 for well reasoned question (and formatted too!). The most likely explanation is that matlab isn't running when `watch` decides to check for it. I would insert `ps aux | grep '[M]ATLAB'` on the line above `pid=...` to see if/what your script is finding. Did you look at `man watch`, are there any clues about syncronizing searches like your trying? Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @shellter. I should have mentioned this in the question: The matlab is indeed running the entire time. I can see it on `top` with the same pid all the time. I also know from the job that matlab is running that it takes several hours, and won't be terminated while I run `watch`. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I have just tested your script. but it works just fine on my computer!

Comment: well not to be a broken record, I would insert `ps aux | grep '[M]ATLAB'`, above where you set `pid=...`, allowing the output to echo to your screen, thus giving you a real-time debugging output ;-). Think of it this way, keep taking out extra features, in this case `pid=\`...\``, until you see where something has changed and not giving the results you would expect. That code looks like it would work, (and outside of `watch` it does), so there must be something about how `watch` is running your script that you'll only see if you go to a debug mode. Or try adding `set -vx` near top. Good luck!

Comment: @MohammadRazeghi: I don't know why you can't replicate it. I tried it on my personal ubuntu laptop (12.04), and it didn't work there either. If you don't have matlab, just run something else (but only one instance), like firefox.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks I followed your advice, and simplified the hell out of it. Apparently it boils down to this: `ps ax | grep MATLAB` finds the real instance of matlab (plus grep line itself), but `watch "ps ax | grep MATLAB"` does not. I don't have any more time to look into it right now. So, will use pidof as Jotne suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
pid=`ps aux | grep '[M]ATLAB' | awk '{print $2}'`
```

could be changed to:

```
pid=$(pidof MATLAB)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works. I just need to use `pidof -x` if want to look for scripts too. Or use `pgrep` instead.

Although I still don't know why watch does not work with my grep MATLAB in the first place :) will wait a bit to see anyone has an explanation for that one, or if I get a chance to look more into it myself. Otherwise will accept yours.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a loop with sleep command instead?

For example:

```
 #!/bin/bash
pid=`ps aux | grep '[M]ATLAB' | awk '{print $2}'`

while [ "1" ]
do
if [[ -n $pid ]]
then
    \grep VmSize /proc/$pid/status
else
    echo "no pid"
fi
sleep 10
done
```

Here the script sleeps(waits) for 10 seconds. You can set the interval you need changing the sleep command. For example to make the script sleep for an hour use `sleep 1h`.

To exit the script press Ctrl - C

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I just ended up using Jotne suggestion as it was a bit simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why it's not working in watch but you could use a cron job and make the script log to a file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$(pidof MATLAB) # Just to follow previously given advice :)
if [[ -n $pid ]]
then
    echo "$(date): $(\grep VmSize /proc/$pid/status)" >> logfile
else
    echo "$(date): no pid" >> logfile
fi
```

You'd of course have to create logfile with touch.

Comment: Not really related to my question: I do the logging outside of this script, but just for the record, I think (and just tested/confirmed on my machine) you don't really need to touch logfile first. If it doesn't exist, it is automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

You might try just running ps command in watch.  I have had issues in the past with watch chopping lines and such when they get too long.

It can be fixed by making the terminal you are running the command from wider or changing the column like this (may need to adjust the 160 to your liking):
export COLUMNS=160;